# How can I remove this %20 from my jekyll github page link?

Tags: github, url, jekyll

I think I have narrowed it down to this line in the _site/header.html

`<a class="site-title" rel="author" href="{{ " /" | relative_url }}">`

I have tried changing the stuff inside the curly braces to my_page.url .. but it totally breaks the title link. Right now my github page goes to the right place, but when I use the title link it gives 404 and the browser url has an additional /%20/

I have tried removing the space in " /", but when I save it it adds it back.

Answer (score 0):

looked into the repo changes i made and undid the change to this line.

`<a class="site-title" rel="author" href="/">`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this problem: Disable `Editor: Format on save` in vscode. vscode was injecting spaces in Jekyll html templates that it was treating like html files. Disabling `Editor: Format on save` in the settings fixed the issue.